# 64 bit kernel, 32/64 bit userland

Tags: linux-kernel, 32bit-64bit, x86-64

I have a 32 bit userland and kernel.(rhel5 based)
I have already updated kernel to 64 bit. 32 bit userland application successfully runs on 64 bit kernel. 
Now I also want to use 64 bit userland binaries with 32 bit userland together. 
What should be my next steps?

Comment: What errors are you getting when you try to run 64bit applications?

Comment: "
# ./ping64
-bash: ./ping64: cannot execute binary file"
Because there are no any glibc for x86_64 on the system

Comment: Why can't you use your distros package manager to install glibc in 64 bit version?

Comment: It can not find any x86_64 packages when searching. Also can not find in casee "yum install glibc.x86_64" type command.

Comment: This should really be migrated to unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a new repository that contains 64 bit userland [[repository] Options](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-yum-yumconf-repository.html).

[Here](http://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/rhel) is one, but it is for Red Hat 7.